# Why can't I bind ListBoxItem's Foreground color?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I've got a ListBox that uses a Style to define how the ListBoxItems look. Here is the style:

```
<Style x:Key="OutputListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
  <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Consolas" />
  <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="12" />
  <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling" />
  <Setter Property="hyp:ListBoxSelector.Enabled" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource OutputListBoxItemStyle}" />
  <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Command="Copy" />
      </ContextMenu>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="OutputListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor}"
          FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"/>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

As you can see, the Foreground property of the TextBlock within the ListBoxItem is binding to my object's ForegroundColor property. I've also tried binding with a Setter in the ListBoxItem itself instead of the TextBlock, and having the TextBlock use a TemplateBinding like the Background property, but this also doesn't work. Here is the object I am binding to:

```
public class PrintInfo : ViewModelBase
{
    protected Brush foreColor;

    public String Text { get; set; }
    public Brush ForegroundColor { get { return foreColor; } set { foreColor = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ForegroundColor"); } }

    public PrintInfo()
    {
        ForegroundColor = Brushes.White;
    }

    public PrintInfo(String text) : base()
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

The text is being printed, but with no foreground color, so it isn't visible. I want the foreground color to be white. I've seen other SO questions that bind in a very similar way to what I'm trying to do, so I'm confused why this isn't working. Here's the ListBox itself:

```
<ListBox Name="OutputBox" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Output,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}"
                  Style="{StaticResource OutputListBoxStyle}">
```

EDIT 1: Added the ListBox's style to this example per Rohit's request.
EDIT 2: Just so people don't have to search through my comments, the problem wasn't in any of my XAML, it was in my custom object, `PrintInfo`. I was calling `: base()` instead of `: this()`, and expecting the default constructor to be called, which of course it wasn't, the superclass constructor was being called. The Foreground color was never set because of this, and thus my invisible text results.

Comment: How do you know that the text is being printed if it isn't visible? Did you use something like Snoop? If you hard-code the foreground in the XAML, does your text appear? I don't see anything wrong with what you have shown.

Comment: @TyCobb Two things show me the text is printing: when I hardcode the color, it shows up, and when I don't, I can select the ListBoxItems and they change to the highlight trigger color which makes them visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, ***ListBoxItem style is not applied anywhere on ListBox instance***. Moreover, I don't see any need to override the Template of ListBoxItem, you can set the **`ItemTemplate`** like this:

```
<ListBox Name="OutputBox" Grid.Column="0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Output, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                                AncestorType=Window}}"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
         Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}"
         Style="{StaticResource OutputListBoxStyle}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ForegroundColor}"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                                         Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Yes it is. It's applied in this line: Style="{StaticResource OutputListBoxStyle}". I will try switching to a DataTemplate, but I want this style to be on multiple ListBox's, so I'm definitely not putting it directly under each ListBox instance.

Comment: `OutputListBoxStyle` is style of ListBox. But for ListBoxItem it is `OutputListBoxItemStyle` which I don't see applied in posted code. And yeah you can declare template as resource and can apply using StatiResource on ItemTemplate.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't include the ListBox style in the code example. I'll add it now - it uses OutputListBoxItemStyle though.

Comment: I've converted to a DataTemplate and have exactly the same issues that I'm having with the ControlTemplate.

Comment: Before applying `ItemTemplate` have you get rid of `OutputListBoxItemStyle`? You don't need listBoxItem style. Also, I tried in small sample with your dummy data and it works fine for me.

Comment: I simplified the code in the example because I didn't want it to get too large. I'm using the style to apply other properties,  like alignment, margin, and padding. On top of that, it also sets the Template. I'll see if I can create a small sample using all the things I apply in the style, and I'll post a link to it here so you can look at it.

Comment: Hmm. I created a simple sample and it works with foreground binding. The thing is, I've got nearly identical code to my main project as far as the ListBox's are concerned so I'm not sure where the problem is... investigating some more..

Comment: Ok, I have no idea what's wrong. My test application now has identical code in both XAML and code behind for the ListBox's, and I'm applying my theme, and still the test app works but the main app doesn't.

Comment: Oh man... the mistake was so small I'm not surprised no one caught it. I use the 2nd constructor of PrintInfo, which calls "base()" instead of "this()", and the Foreground color never gets set. When I switch to "this()" to use the default constructor, I get all the colors I want. Marking Rohit's answer as correct.