Coloring the Checkbox's Foreground/Background property is not working
In my WPF application I am trying to set the Foreground and Background colors of the checkbox's Content text based on a property binding. I already tested this property change on another control, a TextBlock, and I do see the text block's foreground changing based on the property value. But I am not sure what am I doing wrong to the checkbox. Here is my code in Xaml
 <ListBox Name="FooListView" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding FooCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
   SelectionMode="Multiple"
   Background="Transparent">
     <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
             <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
         </Style>
     </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                 <Image MaxWidth="64" MaxHeight="64" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
                 <Separator Width="20" Background="Transparent"/>
                 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}">
                     <WrapPanel>
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                                    Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor}" 
                                    Background="{Binding BackgroundColor}"/>
                     </WrapPanel>
                 </CheckBox>
             </DockPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>


Wpf controls are look less. There's a default template for each. This is the checkbox template https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/checkbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

If setting properties doesn't give you the results you want then replace the template.

@Andy still not working. I managed to successfully make a template but I don't know where to bind these properties to change colors. I thought this was something you just simply bind to the Foreground and Background properties just like you would bind them to a label or TextBox property.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152302/why-cant-i-bind-listboxitems-foreground-color
